# postgresql count null and blank value from jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, json

In following JSON structure,

```json
[
    ["a", 921],
    ["b", ""],
    ..
    ...  
    ["c", null],
]
```

how to count occurrence of

1. blank value ""
2. null value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to convert your array into a set of elements. Each element is itself an array, so you can use the [`->`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) operator to retrieve the second element. Once you have them, use a standard `count(*)`, with the corresponding [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

You can do it with the following SQL statement (the `WITH` helps you view the "step-by-step" approach):

```
WITH original_data(var) AS
(
    VALUES (
    '
    [
        ["a", 921],
        ["b", ""],
        ["c", null]
    ]
    '::json)   -- Note the ::json to make sure PostgreSQL uses the proper type
)
, second_elements AS
(
SELECT 
    json_array_elements(var)->1 AS e
FROM
    original_data
)
SELECT
    count(e) AS total_elements,
    count(e) FILTER (WHERE e::text = '""') AS blank_elements,
    count(e) FILTER (WHERE e::text = 'null') AS null_elements
FROM
    second_elements ;
```

... or the following one:

```
SELECT
    count(e) AS total_elements,
    count(e) FILTER (WHERE e = '""') AS blank_elements,
    count(e) FILTER (WHERE e = 'null') AS null_elements
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        (json_array_elements(var)->1)::text AS e
    FROM
        (
        VALUES (
        '
        [
            ["a", 921],
            ["b", ""],
            ["c", null]
        ]
        '::json)
        ) AS original_data(var)
) AS second_elements ;
```

In both cases, you get:

```
 total_elements | blank_elements | null_elements
 -------------: | -------------: | ------------:
              3 |              1 |             1
```

You can check everything at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=577db6914eb88c9935022bbd33641947).

NOTE: If you want to use `jsonb` instead of `json`, just change the `::json`with `::jsonb` in the first statement, and call the `jsonb_array_elements` instead of `json_array_elements`.